# How to access variable of a function in one python file in another python file

Tags: python, tkinter

Python file 1 login.py

```
def login_screen():
    username_text = tk.Entry(frame2,textvariable = username_var, width=15,font = 'Times 25')
login = tk.Tk()
```

Python file 2 packages.py

```
def package_screen():
    username = login.username_text.get()
packages = tk.Tk
```

> Cannot find reference 'username_text' in 'login.py'

I want to get the username entered by the user in file 1
I keep getting this error

**AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'username_text'**
Does anyone know what it means????

Comment: Since you have used `textvariable=username_var`, did you try `login.username_var.get()` instead?

Comment: Yes I did but that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you want but I guess you need to import login.py.

```
import login as lgn

def package_screen():
    username = lgn.login.username_text.get()
packages = tk.Tk
```

Comment: I have actually imported login but I get the same error

Comment: import login,travel

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how you can access ```username_text``` from anywhere other than within the ```login_screen``` function since it is a local variable within that function.   If  someone can clarify, I'd be appreciated.

Comment: I want to get the username entered by the user in file 1 so that I can display the username in file 2 . If there is a way we can connect do let me know as stackoverflow won't let me share the entire code

Comment: @ewong so is there any other way by converting it into a global variable.If so do let me know